# Complex equation with real coefficients

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Solve

$$(A - z^2) (B - z^2) = C\dfrac{ (z + i D)^2}{(z - i D)^2}$$

for $z \in \mathbb{C}$ where $A,B,C,D \in \mathbb{R}>0$.

Comment: Please write an *informative* title... one that relates to the specific content of your question.

Comment: what is the context of this?